# Is there a way to control Blender's GUI remotely?

Tags: interface, network

I would like to control Blender on a remote server (Ubuntu, local network) from my Notebook (Windows 7).

Until now I evaluated the following configurations, none of them works satisfactorily.

#### 1 VNC (followed [this tutorial](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-server-12-04/))

Result: Applications like Firefox, Libre-Office work but Blender's UI is rendered incomplete and unusable.

[image]

#### 2 MobaXTerm

[MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) supports SSH and comes with its own X-Server:
Again firefox and other apps work but Blender crashes:

```
$ blender
Color management: using fallback mode for management
connect failed: No such file or directory
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadRenderRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  146 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_GLXRender)
  Serial number of failed request:  154
  Current serial number in output stream:  179
```

#### 3 Run Ubuntu under VMWare and Tunnel X through SSH

Blender starts flawless but the connection (100MBit/s) is so slow that it takes 2-3s to open a menu. [Instructions on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203173/run-application-on-local-machine-and-show-gui-on-remote-display)

Is there an alternative to the methods I tried?

#### Solution

The MobaXterm settings that worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Would an NX session work?

Comment: There was decent local X server for windows, tried it couple years ago: [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).
Never tested any heavier applications though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of MobaXterm works great with Blender! I just had to check the "Hardware OpenGL acceleration" in order to make it work (under "Settings" --> "Configuration" --> "X11" tab.

I started a SSH connection with compression enabled in order to lower bandwidth usage and started Blender which now works correctly.

I am running the latest free version of MobaXterm from http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net and my Windows computer has a nVidia Geforce GT640 with the latest nVidia drivers.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, after setting the X11 server display mode to "Rootless" it now works.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use [Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/) it's free for personal use in your local network. You can also transfer sound to your local device and stream videos. The mouse is a bit laggy but modeling works. Due to the mouse lag it's not suitable for games.