# Blender not starting on Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, opengl

I got a very tricky problem:
Let's begin in the past.
I got a Workstation. In the past it ran Blender 2.78b with a Nvidia Quadro FX1800 as Graphics Card. For Rendering, I used the CPU.
I used another Computer to work on the Workstation via Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection. The Host Computer (The Workstation) has Win 10 Pro, the Client Win 10 Home.
I bought a new Graphics Card for rendering: *ASUS ROG Strix GeForce® GTX 1080*. I replaced the Quadro with it.
I started the PC and Blender (still 2.78b) and rendered the Pavillon Demo Scene. Everything worked perfectly.
But when I tried to start Blender via Remote Desktop and got this:

[image: blender error]

I also tried to use TeamViewer like they mentioned in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/how-to-run-blender-through-rdp-on-windows-server-2008-r2-opengl-error), but got the same error.
I also tried Blender 2.78c, but got also the error message.

Does someone know or experienced the same problem?

Comment: WIndows Remote Desktop Protocol does not support OpenGL. This is not an issue with blender but how Remote desktop works. You can try other forms of remote sharing like VNC

Comment: Please don't host images for questions on google drive, use the tools included on this site, so that the images show as part of the question. Please read through the following link to understand how to add images in your posts: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Comment: other related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15803/is-there-a-way-to-control-blenders-gui-remotely and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61810/how-to-bypass-opengl-1-2-requirement-for-remote-gpu-rendering/61842#61842